# Vaadin & Lombok - Grid component does not apply changes to my beans?

Tags: java, spring, grid, vaadin, lombok

I am new to Vaadin. I like to use the Grid component to edit a list of beans. When I edit in cell the value the changes get not applied to my beans. So what I missing here?

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    ...
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

    PersonDAO personDAO = (PersonDAO) context.getBean("personDAO");
    List<Person> personList = personDAO.getPerson();

    BeanItemContainer<Person> ds = 
            new BeanItemContainer<Person>(Person.class, personList);

    Grid grid = new Grid("Person",ds);
    grid.setEditorEnabled(true);

    setContent(layout);
}
```

Comment: I found the problem. I am using for my Bean [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) which generates automatically the Setter and Getters in Bytecode.
Somehow it seems to cause problems for Vaadin? If I write the getters and Setters myself it worked.
Does somebody experience same problems with Lombok and Vaadin?

Comment: Of course it is not the getter and setter method. It is the @Data annotation of Lombok which generates also the Equals and HashCode methods. Soemhow it seems not to work properly with vaadin. Other facing similar problems [link](http://rjdkolb.blogspot.ch/2012/08/et-tu-richard-i-stabbed-myself-in-back.html)

Comment: You can post an answer of your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I reduce the equals and hashcode method to use just the "id" it works with Vaadin & Lombok.

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"id"}) // this is the trick
public class Person {

    public Person() {}

    public Person(int id, String name) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
    }

    private int id;

    private String name;

}
```